# TensorFlow.js How to train output = input+1

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensor, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow.js

I am trying to learn TensorFlow.js and trying to train it so when a input is given, the output should be input+1.

My code:

```
const model = tf.sequential();


const hiddenLayer = tf.layers.dense({
    inputShape: [1],
    activation: "sigmoid",
    units: 1
});

const outputLayer = tf.layers.dense({
    activation: "sigmoid",
    units: 1
});


model.add(hiddenLayer);
model.add(outputLayer);


model.compile({
    loss: "meanSquaredError",
    optimizer: tf.train.sgd()
})





const trainedDataInput =  [1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 100, 200];
const trainedDataOutput = [2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 101, 201];
const trainedDataInputTensor = tf.tensor(trainedDataInput);
const trainedDataOutputTensor = tf.tensor(trainedDataOutput);


model.fit(trainedDataInputTensor, trainedDataOutputTensor);

const toPredict = tf.tensor([8]);
model.predict(toPredict).print();
```

The output always seems to be between 0.1 and 0.9.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: A sigmoid output function always returns a value between 0 and 1. You can try replacing it with a linear function!

Comment: @Kokodoko Thanks for your answer! I replaced `activation: "sigmoid"` with `activation: "linear"` on both layers but now it gives numbers between -2 and 2. Do I also need to change `optimizer: tf.train.sgd()`? EDIT: Is there a tutorial series on TensorFlow.js you recommend?

Comment: NN usually work in the range `0-1` or `-1, +1` depending on activation functions used.  So what you will need to do is normalise your output, you can also normalise your input, but's that's not as important as your first sigmoid is kind of going to do that.

Comment: @Keith Thanks for your answer! I tried different things but I can't figure it out. How would I do this?

Comment: You first are going to have to decide how big a number,  if we assume your going to teach the NN to count +1 up to 1000,  then simple divide by a 1000,.. And then when you want the answer just multiple by a 1000. etc.  IOW:  using say inputs like inputs `[0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 0.0100, 0.0200]` and outputs as `[0.002, 0.003, 0.004, 0.0101, 0.0201]' etc, and it should be able to learn.  But I would say this isn't really a classic NN problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

+1 to what kokodoko said. The sigmoid activation is typically used for binary classification. To do linear regression, you need a linear (the default) activation.

Other issues with your code:
1. For linear regression, you'll need only one dense layer.
2. The input examples should have a shape of [numExamples, 1], which is [8, 1] in your case.
3. You need to specify how many epochs to train the model for during the `fit()` call.

See the corrected code below.

```js
const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.dense({
    inputShape: [1],  // 'linear' is the default activation, so no need to specify it.
    units: 1
}));

model.compile({loss: 'meanSquaredError', optimizer: 'sgd'})

const trainedDataInput =  [1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 100, 200];
const trainedDataOutput = [2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 101, 201];
const trainedDataInputTensor = tf.tensor(trainedDataInput, [8, 1])
const trainedDataOutputTensor = tf.tensor(trainedDataOutput, [8, 1])

const history = await model.fit(trainedDataInputTensor, trainedDataOutputTensor, {epochs: 100});
```